# Firefox Quantum REST client?

Tags: rest, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-quantum

Pre-version 57 of Firefox had many wonderful add-ons for REST API testing. These REST clients no longer work with Firefox Quantum. While I found some simple, pre 1.0 add-ons in Quantum ([click here for example](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rested/)), my hunch is that there must be something more robust that is on par with the pre-57 version add-ons. Or perhaps even BUILT-IN to Firefox Quantum Developer? I would like for someone to answer this post with current options for REST Clients in Firefox Quantum Developer - either built-in, or, as an add-on - that will bring me up to speed and have the same robust qualities of the pre-57 versions.

For example I used to use these two, now not supported:

1. RESTEasy ([click here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rest-easy/))
2. RESTClient ([click here](http://restclient.net/))

One one think that googling "Firefox Quantum Developer Rest Client How to" would result in something that would answer my question. If you do try this make sure to switch from Any Time to "previous year" - this will filter out many pre-57 search results. What will find is only one listed: ([click here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rested/)) - which I am sure you will agree with me that is barely a pre-release and needs more time to mature before being production ready.

So what is going on here? Does Firefox Quantum has a REST Client integrated and I simply cannot find it? What are the professionals using for their REST Client needs with Firefox Quantum? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [version 3.0.2](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/restclient/versions/?page=1#version-3.0.2) (from November 28, 2017), [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/restclient/) supports Firefox 57:

> Upgrade to web extension to support new Firefox. OAuth and OAuth 2.0 authentication is still under development. It will be ready in next version (3.0.3).

Thus, just update your addons.

> ...which I am sure you will agree with me that is barely a pre-release
>   and needs more time to mature before being production ready.

Well,

```
+------------------------+----------------+
| Add-on (57-compatible) | Overall rating |
+------------------------+----------------+
| RESTClient             | 3.7 out of 5   |
| RESTED                 | 4.0 out of 5   |
| RESTer                 | 4.5 out of 5   |
+------------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

How about a standalone tool?

You can check out [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the request by turning on the Firefox developer tools 'Menu->Web Developer->Toggle Tools.

I just run the GET request from the URL bar, and then edit the request to Post.

Click on the 'Network' tab, and you can edit the failed GET request. Select the request, click on Edit and Resend on the right, and change GET to POST

Comment: and what to do with, when I click "edit and resend" and it closes request detail area? So there is nowhere to enter anything.

Comment: @Dainius After you hit "Send" in the "Edit and Resend" window, the detail area will close and the request will be sent. If you want the details on the new request, you need to click on it in the Network panel again.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try new extension built for Firefox Quantum, like [Resting](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/resting?utm_source=stackoverflow.com)

Resting is a Firefox addons that works perfectly for Firefox Quantum and works for daily usage

Answer (score 0):

If you was comfortable using RESTEasy I suggest to give a try to [Resting](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/resting?utm_source=stackoverflow.com) too.
If think Resting is easy to use as RESTEasy, but it has more useful features